# Pass-Through stream not emitting finish event

Tags: node.js

I try to pipe a series of pass-through streams using the [through2](https://github.com/rvagg/through2) module. At the end I'm gonna use this in a unit test using Jasmine.

If I understand correctly omitting the transform function will return a pass-through stream. A pass-through stream is a [Transform](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough) stream that should emit a `finish` event, right?

What am I missing in the following example? I would expect it to output `fooobar`

```
var through = require('through2');

through()
 .pipe(through())
 .on('finish', function() { 
      console.log('fooobar'); 
 });
```

`node -v v0.12.2`
`through2 v2.0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first stream that's being piped is not ending. Try something like this:

```
var through = require('through2');

var stream = through();
stream.pipe(through())
      .on('finish', function() { 
        console.log('fooobar'); 
      });
stream.end();
```